# Snowflake Query history Execution_Status issue

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to find the list of query id's that are running for more than an hour in snowflake.

Based on the snowflake history, I'm trying to get all the query id's that have `EXECUTION_STATUS = 'RUNNING'`

```
select * from table(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY_BY_SESSION()) where lower(EXECUTION_STATUS) = 'running';
```

To test the above query, I kept running an infinite loop query to see if this will be captured by the above query

```
with rec as (
    select  1 as n
    union all
    select  n + 1 from    rec
)
select n from rec
```

When I run this `select * from table(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY_BY_SESSION()) where lower(EXECUTION_STATUS) = 'running';` it is only showing this query execution status as 'RUNNING' and the infinite query is not being shown as RUNNING. I don't understand what I'm missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the check query is run using different sessions(it is true for multiple worksheets in Snowsight UI), therefore using `QUERY_HISTORY_BY_USER` or by explicitly providing session_id would be more appropriate:

```
select * 
from table(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY_BY_SESSION()) 
where EXECUTION_STATUS ILIKE 'running';

=>

select * 
from table(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY_BY_USER()) 
where EXECUTION_STATUS ILIKE 'running';

-- xyz value copied from original query session
select * 
from table(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY_BY_SESSION(SESSION_ID=>xyz)) 
where EXECUTION_STATUS ILIKE 'running';
```

Session Id could be checked by running `SELECT CURRENT_SESSION()`

Comment: Yes, you're right. Replacing `table(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY_BY_SESSION())` with `table(information_schema.query_history())` worked